# AppDelegate Extension not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, core-location, appdelegate

I am trying to get the users location immediately on start up, and to do this I have implemented a global variable `userLocation` that will get updated in the AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function. I have implemented the location manager like so:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
    return true
}
```

and the extension:

```
extension AppDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        usersLocation = locations.last!
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

The userLocation never gets updated, and I placed a break point on the `userLocation = locations.last!` line and it never reaches that.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should keep the `locationManager` variable too.

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: thanks, that ended up working but it was still not working quick enough for my needs, I'll probably just add some loading animation before any user interaction instead